# flash video gallery in flash cc and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

So i been trying to create to create a flash video gallery for my website but im getting an error on it even though the code should be correct

Below is the code i came up with

```
stop();

one.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid1);
two.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid2);
three.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid3);
four.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid4);
five.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid5);

function vid1(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    vidPlayer.source ="flv/01.flv"

}

function vid2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    vidPlayer.source ="flv/02.flv"

}

function vid3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    vidPlayer.source ="flv/03.flv"

}

`enter code here`function vid4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    vidPlayer.source ="flv/04.flv"

}

function vid5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    vidPlayer.source ="flv/05.flv"

}

vidPlayer.playButton = player
vidPlayer.pauseButton = pauser
```

Does anyone have any idea on whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Please show some details of the error (exception msg, etc.)

Comment: It comes up with error code 1071 and says that there's a syntax error on this line. It basicly says that there should be a void here 

one.add Eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid1);

Comment: So now i moved the opening curly brackets so that they are after void in my functions and the error message remains the same. Only now though the keyword missing is function

Answer (score 0):

[`addEventlistener`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) is a function, which will register an event listener object, and the name of a function should never contain spaces which is your error, so you should write :

```
one.addEventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid1);
two.addEventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid2);
three.addEventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid3);
four.addEventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid4);
five.addEventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK,vid5);
```

Hope that can help.